# Passwords: Speed of conversion from displayed to 'starred'

Tags: password

On an Android phone, passwords are automatically converted to a 'starred' format a few seconds after each character is input.  However I find this happens too quickly to visually double check that I have input the right character.

Is there any research / guidelines on how long a password character should be displayed before automatically being hidden ?

Comment: I personally feel that it's too long, to be honest! Still curious, though!

Answer (score 2):

To take the opposite stance of SlaKrop: I feel that the "starred" format has no place on a hand held device.  It's too easy to screw up typing using an on screen keyboard while at the same time it's very hard to look over someone's shoulder as they type.

See this: http://www.nngroup.com/articles/stop-password-masking/

I've seen a few places that now use a checkbox on the password entry screens so that you can optionally turn off the "starred" format.  This is a great way of giving the users the option on how to handle it.

Comment: I'd certainly agree that being able to turn off the starred format would help as it gives the user control.  However there must be an optimum 'hiding' time which is a play off between the user being able to see what they've typed and it being automatically hidden if its left on screen too long.

Comment: To update June 2020: it's interesting to see that being able to turn off the starred format is increasingly offered as an option.